# Getting fgets warning when trying to run optimized c file

Tags: c, warnings, fgets, strtol

This is part of a much larger file, but this is the only function in question. Here's the issue, if I compile it in gcc unoptimized, I will get everything I want without issues. However, if I try to compile it as gcc -c -pg -02 main.c,
I get the following error message

Comment: It's giving you good advice: Check the return value of `fgets` before using `line` in case the function has an error.

Comment: Same way you would check the return value of any function. Read the manual page to see what value it returns on error and then check for it with an `if` condition: `if (fgets(line,MAX_LINE ,stdin) == NULL) { /* do error handling */ }`

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. And a good one. *Always* check to see if an input function succeeded before trying to use the value(s) read.

Comment: Don't see what? I find it difficult to believe the compiler still gives that warning after you add error checking to use the return value of fgets. Post the exact updated code and exact warning from that code if you claim it is still happening.

Comment: You should *also* add error checking to conversion functions like `strtol()`. What if you read something that's not an integer? Or has other stuff after some leading digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other function that does input, `fgets` could fail for a variety of reasons.  As you can find from its documentation, if this happens it will return `NULL`.  However since you do not look at its return value, you would never know.  That's what the compiler is trying to warn you about.   If it fails, the array `line` will not contain valid input, and may contain garbage that would cause your program to misbehave if you try to process it.

(There are many situations where some warnings only happen with optimization on; this is because the compiler does a more detailed analysis of the code as part of the optimization process, which makes it more possible for it to detect such issues.  But that's a good thing; it's not a problem with optimization or a reason not to use it.)

If `fgets` should fail, there's no obvious way for your program to recover, so the simplest approach is to just have it quit and display an error message.  The `perror` function is a convenient way to do that; it prints a human-readable message corresponding to the error code from the `errno` variable which `fgets` should set.

So a rudimentary form of error checking here would be to replace your `fgets` line with:

```
if (fgets(line,MAX_LINE ,stdin) == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to read input");
    exit(1);
}
```

Some things you could improve later:

- One possible reason for `fgets` to return NULL is end-of-file: if there was no input at all: the user hit the end-of-file key on their terminal (usually Ctrl-D on Unix, Ctrl-Z on Windows) or redirected input from an empty file.  That's not exactly an error, and it won't result in an error code in `errno`, so `perror` may print a misleading message in this case.  Try and fix this bug.  You could distinguish the two cases using the `ferror` function.
- If a line was successfully read but can't be parsed as a number, `strtol` will fail.  You currently don't check for that either.  Look up how it indicates this failure and handle it accordingly.

Comment: @buckywucky: `strtol` doesn't signal failure by its return value, but rather via its second `endptr` argument.  So you'll have to look up how that works.  It's up to you to decide what to do if it fails.  This could happen if the user types something that isn't a number, which isn't strictly speaking an error, just misuse.  `perror` and `exit` may not be the best way to handle that; you may want to print a more customized message, and/or let the user try again.